# Executing Curl command in scala

Tags: scala, curl

I am trying to execute the curl command through scala for scalatest,
CURL :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/home/examples/demo/demo.json http://localhost:9090/job
```

which works aas expected while I tried doing it with scala ,like

```
import scala.sys.process._
    val json = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(arg0).getPath

    val cmd = Seq("curl", "-H", "'Content-Type: application/json'","-d", s"@$json","http://localhost:9090/job")
    cmd.!
```

and it produces following error

```
Expected 'application/json'
```

Comment: is arg0 a custom variable? because the default for application params is args(0) in a main method

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just use an HTTP client library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quoting too much:

```
Seq("curl", "-H", "'Content-Type: application/json'","-d", s"@$json","http://localhost:9090/job")
//                !^!                            !^!
```

Should be:

```
Seq("curl", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", s"@$json","http://localhost:9090/job")
//                 !                            !
```

The reason you need to quote the content-type in the shell is because the *shell* will break it up if it isn't quoted. Curl doesn't know how to deal with quotes, because quotes aren't its business. Scala won't do any word-splitting, either, because that's your job.