# CURL command in Scala shows: Couldn't read data from file this makes an empty POST

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, curl

I am resetting an Elasticsearch index in my local using scala curl. I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45804956/1773841) as a reference.

In the first step I delete the existing version of the Elasticsearch index by:

```
import scala.sys.process._

val delete_cmd = Seq("curl", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "DELETE", "http://127.0.0.1:9222/my_index")
    delete_cmd.!
```

In the next step I try to recreate that same index passing in the body of the index mapping:

```
val body =
      """
        |{
        |    "settings": {
        |        "index": {
        |            "number_of_shards" : 40,
        |            "number_of_replicas": 0
        |        }
        |    },
        |    "mappings": {
        |        "properties": {
        |            "pk": {
        |                "type": "text",
        |                "analyzer": "keyword"
        |            },
        |            "field1": {
        |                "type": "text"
        |            },
        |            "field2": {
        |                "type": "text"
        |            },
        |            "field3": {
        |                "type": "text"
        |            }
        |        }
        |    }
        |}
        """

val recreate_cmd = Seq("curl", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "PUT", "-d", s"@$body","http://127.0.0.1:9222/my_index")
recreate_cmd.!
```

The index is generated properly after executing `recreate_cmd`, but the mapping and the number of shards I defined in the body are ignored. The warning I am receiving says:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "
        |{
        |    settings: {

Warning:         |        index: {
        |            number_of_shards : 
Warning: 40,
        |            number_of_replicas: 0
        |        }
 
Warning:        |    },
        |    mappings: {
        |        
Warning: properties: {
        |            pk: {
        |                
Warning: type: text,
        |                analyzer: keyword
        |    
Warning:         },
        |            field1: {
        |                
Warning: type: text
        |            },
        |            field2: {
 
Warning:        |                type: text
        |            },
        
Warning: |            field3: {
        |                type: text
        
Warning: |            }
        |        }
        |    }
        |}
      
Warning:   ", this makes an empty POST.
```

How should I pass the body of the CURL command so it is not ignored?

**Edit**:
After removing the @ in the `-data` part of the curl command, as recommended by @Paulo I am getting this new error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}],"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"},"status":500}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

I believe the `@` in you example is the issue.
As per the man documentation of curl:

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename. Data is posted in a similar manner as -d, --data does, except that newlines and carriage returns are preserved and conversions are never done.

## Solution

### About the `Couldn't read data from file`

```scala
val body =
      """
        |{
        |    "settings": {
        |        "index": {
        |            "number_of_shards" : 40,
        |            "number_of_replicas": 0
        |        }
        |    },
        |    "mappings": {
        |        "properties": {
        |            "pk": {
        |                "type": "text",
        |                "analyzer": "keyword"
        |            },
        |            "field1": {
        |                "type": "text"
        |            },
        |            "field2": {
        |                "type": "text"
        |            },
        |            "field3": {
        |                "type": "text"
        |            }
        |        }
        |    }
        |}
        """

val recreate_cmd = Seq("curl", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "PUT", "-d", s"$body","http://127.0.0.1:9222/my_index")
recreate_cmd.!
```

### About the `not_x_content_exception`

I am not sure why this is happening.

I manage to execute a pure curl request with the information you provide and it works.

I believe you might be better of using on the [client elasticsearch has](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html).

Comment: thanks, that actually fixed the issue I was facing, but I am getting another error now. Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes. I will edite the question with the full error. But Thanks for your help, since it was already a progress. I will also remove the ES tag, since as you said the issue is purely in how I am invoking the CURL command, not with ES

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre, the first issue was not related to `elasticsearch` but the new one is ... sorry for asking you to delete the tag

Comment: Thanks, Paulo, you actually solved my original issue, I will investigate or if required add a new post to address the second problem